# CNAME value instead of HOST value

Tags: subdomain, flask, cname, werkzeug

If we have a customer with a cname record, sub1.notourserver.com, pointing to something like abcdefg.ourserver.com, we read the host as sub1.notoursever.com. Is it possible for us to somehow get the value abcdefg.ourserver.com from this request? We have a subdomain route setup, but it is not picking up on it because the host does not match our SERVER_NAME config setting.

Comment: You mean other than querying it from your resolvers?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not provide that information, and so neither can Flask/Werkzeug. You need to use in Flask/Werkzeug the (sub)domain names actually used by clients.

If you really can not do that, you need to hack a WSGI middleware that maintains an explicit mapping (or makes DNS requests) and patches `environ['HTTP_HOST']`.